# Repetition in digits on a normal number

Tags: number-theory, probability-theory

Consider a normal real number $0< n < 1$. Let $n_i$ denote the $i^\text{th}$ digit of $n$. What is the probability that there exists some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n_1=n_{1+k}, n_2=n_{2+k}, \ldots, n_k=n_{2k}$? I know that there are normal numbers that don't satisfy this. Maybe an easier question is if the digits of $n$ are random.

Comment: For random digits (or even bits) the probability of the kind of match you describe is less than $1$.

Comment: For random digits, with $p_k=10^{-k}$, $$p_1+(1-p_1)p_2<p<p_1+(1-p_1)p_2+p_3+p_4+\cdots$$ yields $$.109<p<.112.$$

Comment: Since the set of non-normal reals has measure 0, conditioning on normal numbers has no effect at all on the probability :).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2779957/16397